# Importance of react-router-redux push

Tags: reactjs, react-router-redux

I am using react-router-redux push in my project but not sure why my team is using it in actionsToProps. Is there any special benefit out of it?

push in actionsToProps works fine

```
import {push} from 'react-router-redux';

const actionsToProps = {
      registerUser: actions.registerUser,
      push
    }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actionsToProps)(Register);
```

The reason I am asking this question because my component still works fine without push.

without push in actionsToProps works fine too

```
import {push} from 'react-router-redux';

const actionsToProps = {
      registerUser: actions.registerUser
    }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actionsToProps)(Register);
```

Would request you to clarify if my question doesn't looks like stupid.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux), `push` *"Pushes a new location to history, becoming the current location"*. IE. it is used to change/ open pages via react-router. It is meant as an alternate of `react-router`.

You can use it like:

`store.dispatch(push('/foo'))`

Comment: Ok but why push is being used in actionsToProps along with actions. Any idea?

Comment: Seemingly it provides no benefit other than importing it( `push` ) again from `react-router-redux` wherever `actionToProps` is being used. TBH I haven't seen it used used anywhere. And I think `reduxActions` are meant to be simple ie they should only do one job.